# How to improve model for digit recognition?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, keras

I am making a simple application to implement digit recognition. The problem is that it works wonderfully on the mnist dataset but predicts horribly on random images downloaded from google. What should I do to improve the accuracy of my model?

Another question : Someone suggested to add more layers in the model. If so, how do I add more layers to my model?

File in which model is trained:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import keras
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras import backend as K
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from keras.models import load_model
import pickle
import h5py
import numpy as np
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
batch_size = 128
num_classes = 10
epochs = 12

# input image dimensions
img_rows, img_cols = 28, 28

model=load_model('my_model.h5')



the data, split between train and test sets
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
print('initial shape')
print('x_test ',x_test.shape)
print('y_test ',y_test.shape)


# print(x_test);
# print(y_test.shape)

if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first':
    print('reshape1')
    x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0], 1, img_rows, img_cols)
    x_test = x_test.reshape(x_test.shape[0], 1, img_rows, img_cols)
    input_shape = (1, img_rows, img_cols)
else:
    print('reshape2')
    x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0], img_rows, img_cols, 1)
    x_test = x_test.reshape(x_test.shape[0], img_rows, img_cols, 1)
    input_shape = (img_rows, img_cols, 1)

x_train = x_train.astype('float32')
x_test = x_test.astype('float32')
x_train /= 255
x_test /= 255
print('x_train shape:', x_train.shape)
print('x_test shape: ' , x_test.shape)
print(x_train.shape[0], 'train samples')
print(x_test.shape[0], 'test samples')

print('x_test final : ')
print(x_test)

# convert class vectors to binary class matrices
y_train = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes)
y_test = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test, num_classes)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3),
                 activation='relu',
                 input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.10))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.20))
model.add(Dense(256,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.40))

model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
              optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adadelta(),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train,
          batch_size=batch_size,
          epochs=epochs,
          verbose=1,
          validation_data=(x_test, y_test))

model.save('my_model.h5')
score = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=0)


# print(x_test.shape)
# print('\n')
# print(y_test.shape)

print('Test loss:', score[0])
print('Test accuracy:', score[1])
```

The below code is used for testing my model with my own image

```
image = cv2.imread("2.jpg")
img_rows, img_cols = 28, 28

x_test1 = cv2.resize(image, (28, 28)) 

x_test1 = cv2.cvtColor(x_test1,cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)


print(x_test1.shape)

if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first':
    print('reshape1')
    x_test1 = x_test1.reshape(1, 1, img_rows, img_cols)
    input_shape = (1, img_rows, img_cols)

else:
    print('reshape2')
    x_test1 = x_test1.reshape(1, img_rows, img_cols, 1)
    input_shape = (img_rows, img_cols, 1)

x_test1 = x_test1.astype('float32')
x_test1 /= 255
y_test1 = np.array([[ 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])
score = model.evaluate(x_test1, y_test1, verbose=0)
print('done')
print('score of image = ')
print(score[1])
print(score[0])
score=model.predict_classes(x_test1)
print(score)
```

The below code is used to load a previous trained model and continue training it from the previous checkpoint. If there are any mistakes please do suggest them.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3),
                 activation='relu',
                 input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
              optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adadelta(),
              metrics=['accuracy'])
filepath="my_model.h5"
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(filepath, monitor='acc', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='max')
callbacks_list = [checkpoint]

score=model.fit(x_test1, y_test1,epochs=12, batch_size=128, callbacks=callbacks_list, verbose=0)


new_model = load_model("my_model.h5")
np.testing.assert_allclose(model.predict(x_test1),
                new_model.predict(x_test1),
                1e-5)


checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(filepath, monitor='loss', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='min')
callbacks_list = [checkpoint]
new_model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=12, batch_size=128, callbacks=callbacks_list)
```

Does the above code cause over-fitting of the model ? If yes how do I make it more efficient so that it is able to predict any kind of data ? Help Required!!

Comment: Your code is almost identical to [keras example](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/examples/mnist_cnn.py). What have you tried on your own?

Comment: Maxim This was a pretty standard example for beginners and I wanted to understand how to add layers in order to improve accuracy . I plan on working on my own project soon and I wanted to be clear on my concepts.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be surprised by these results because you train your model on one data domain but test it on a different one. Yes, you may get slightly better performance if you have a better-designed network, but this gap still exists.

To close this gap, you can improve the following things :

1. **improve your training data**: (a) train your model with more real-looking digit data, for example, the street view house number ([SVHN](http://ufldl.stanford.edu/housenumbers/)) dataset, or the digits in the [char74K](http://www.ee.surrey.ac.uk/CVSSP/demos/chars74k/) dataset, and (b) train your model with better data augmentation techniques, for example, blend a digit sample with a random background image.
2. **adapt your testing data**: preprocess testing samples such that they look similar to those in your training data, for example, binzarize a testing sample and let it look similar to that of MNIST, before you feed it to your network for prediction.
3. **improve your model** by explicitly considering the variations in real data: for example, if you think it is `rotation` in testing data degrades your model performance, then you can consider this factor in your model training by adding a side task to prediction digit rotation; or you believe a good model should only predict digits but not the dataset that this training sample belongs to, then you can add an adversarial task to force the network *forget* this information.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help ! I will work on what you said and I was wondering if using SVM would help with accuracy ?